# How can I query Active Directory to display a list of users?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, extension-request

I am using Joomla to build a company Intranet.  We would like to display a nicely formatted list of users as a Company Directory.  We already have all this information in our Windows Domain / Active Directory structure, so there's no need to duplicate the data - I just need to query AD and have it return the user list in a format I can display in Joomla.

Two options that may accomplish this:

1) Does a component exist that does this?  (I saw several Address Book components, but none seemed to connect to an AD structure.)

2) I can use Sourcerer from NoNumber to insert PHP code into an article, and have it return the list.  What would be the code to display all users in an AD OU and its children?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Simple Google search for "joomla windows active directory users" returns bunch of very viable answers regarding integrating Joomla and AD by usng LDAP, which turns out to be pretty common feature. I have no personal experience with that in order to validate these links.

Comment: That doesn't help me, then.  I'm not looking to authenticate Joomla via LDAP, I am looking to display the results of an AD query within Joomla as  a page for viewing.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [JMapMyLDAP Tools](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jmapmyldap-tools) and was very satisfied with it.

You alse have nice article on Joomla Community Portal: [JOOMLA! LDAP AUTHENTICATIONS PLUGIN: WINDOW 2003 SERVER ACTIVE DIRECTORY CONFIGURATION](https://community.joomla.org/gsoc2009/lalitanand-dandge/908-joomla-ldap-authentications-plugin-window-2003-server-active-directory-configuration.html) which is good read about Joomla an LDAP.

Comment: This lets me authenticate, but it does not return a list of AD users as a set of results I can use in a directory.  I'm already using it to authenticate and log on, and I do agree it's great, it's just not the tool I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, I got what I needed using a combination of tools:

https://samjlevy.com/use-php-and-ldap-to-list-members-of-an-active-directory-group-v3/

to get the listing itself, although this was a stand-alone PHP script, and:

http://2glux.com/projects/jumi

To embed the script inside Joomla, and output the results inside Joomla itself.

I'm still tweaking the output of the PHP script to get the results I want, but it's getting there.

Comment: Good for you... Thanx for sharing the solution with us.